# How to stop a div from recognizing HTML tags when inserting text on it with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

```
div.innerHTML = my_text;
```

The code above has a problem: HTML tags are rendered. I want the opposite behavior: I want `<b>` to render as the string, not making anything bold. I also want to be able to use "\t" and "\n" as newline and tab characters. What can I do?

Comment: innerText is not cross-browser. It also does not render "\t" tab characters. I ask future voters to actually read the entire question before judging.

Comment: Where is `innerText` mentioned? Also, rendering tab characters is a matter of a `replace` operation.

Comment: (createTextNode too doesn't render tab characters)

Comment: @Viclib replace \t with four spaces...

Comment: But four spaces aren't rendered too :/

Comment: check my answer (updated)

Answer (score 3):

To prevent HTML from being rendered, simply escape it:

```
div.innerHTML = my_text.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
```

This will still allow HTML entities such as `&eacute;` from being parsed. If you also want these to appear raw, tag this to the end of the line:

```
.replace(/&/g,"&amp;");
```

Alternatively, try this "cleaner" option:

```
while(div.firstChild) div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(my_text));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using div.innerHTML when you should be using div.innerText.

innerText is not cross browser, I recommend you to use a library like jQuery so you don't have this type of issues:

using jQuery you could write something like

```
$('#you_div').text(str.replace(/\t/g," "));
```

The replace above replaces your '\t' to "\t" so you will see \t on the text.

Anyway the standard seems to be the property textContent.
Here is some info in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.textContent).

---

A different solution that better suites your needs probably is to get the text encoded and then replace the `'\t'` with `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` , in this solution use the property innerHTML instead.

Comment: It does not render \t characters.

Comment: that's because your string has the caracter '\t' perform a regex.replace of '\t' to "\\t" this will do the trick. here is an example: var result = str.replace(patt1,"\\t"); in this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_t replace the line search with the code before.

Comment: I've done so, both on my site and on that link. It just renders "\t" itself, not a tab...

Comment: i understood you wanted that... guess i misunderstood you.

Comment: just replace \t for "    " four spaces...

Comment: Four spaces are not rendered too :( The only way I got a quasi-correct result was by replacing it with underscores.